# Capture data using wireshark through ethernet Switch

Tags: switch-statement, wireshark, capture, packet, ethernet

I need to capture data from the device(FPGA Board) which is connected to the Ethernet Switch. From the Switch I connected my Laptop which having wireshark to capture data. Using the above setup I cant able see the packets in wireshark, but if I directly connecting the FPGA to Laptop without using Switch I can able to capture data in wireshark. Kindly help me on this

Answer (score 2):

By default your laptop will only see broadcast & unknown unicast frames. In order to see frames to/from the FPGA board you need to configure the switch to mirror (or SPAN) traffic to your laptop.